# My apology to people I offended

Tags: discussion

I just want to say that I have recently been rude and an ass on this website, anger and ego got the better of me and I said some harsh rude things to people and I'm sorry. I don't want to be like that and I'm trying really hard to be aware but sometimes I allow negative afflictive emotions to control what I say and do. I hope I haven't caused anyone any suffering because really it's the last thing I want to do. I really struggle with differing opinions sometimes. It's hard to accept that other people have such different opinions to my own but this is life. I hope those affected by my insensitivity can accept my apology and I will try my hardest to not slip again.

Comment: Congratulations on your achievement!  It goes against the grain of human nature to seek awareness of our mistakes and shortcomings.  It's so nice to see people having moments of clarity, they are not always easy to come by.

Answer (score 3):

For all worldlings these kind of situation arise. More so if one has a hateful temperament:

> Greedy: the ten foulness meditations; or, body contemplation.
>
> Hating: the four brahma-viharas; or, the four color kasinas.
>
> Deluded: mindfulness of breath.
>
> Faithful: the first six recollections.
>
> Intelligent: recollection of marana or Nibbana; the perception of disgust of food; or, the analysis of the four elements.
>
> Speculative: mindfulness of breath.

[Kammaṭṭhāna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamma%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADh%C4%81na)

Also I have seen Forgiveness Meditation book through not read it: Guide to Forgiveness Meditation: An Effective Method to Dissolve the Blocks to Loving-Kindness, and Living Life Fully by Ven. Bhante Vimalaramsi

Also the person on the receiving end also should try to practice equanimity and if anger arises Metta. More on this see [Vitakka Saṇṭhāna Sutta](http://dharmafarer.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/1.6-Vitakka-Santhana-S-m20.pdf). And also forgive because getting angry on this leads to suffering, this again is easy said than done, but with practice one should become better at forgiving also.